# What's difference between Asp.NEt core and MVC 6 ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in web application programming what 's the difference between Asp. Net and MVC ? 
is it fine to study MVC without any experience in Asp core ?

Comment: Did you even bother to google either MVC or asp.net? I bet both have Wikipedia pages that'll make the difference clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET is a framework. You can create web projects, desktop applications, console applications with this Framework. ASP stands for Active Server Pages. This is a framework for Web applications. However, you can use several approaches. You can work in MVC (Model View Controller) or WebForms.

To answer your questions: yes, ASP.NET MVC depends on ASP.NET which depends on .NET, so it is not a bad thing to know as much as possible about your dependencies, but you can start off by learning to work with MVC directly. That is a possible way as well. The result will be that you will know a lot about MVC and about the dependencies anyway.